# How can I sync my own kernel function in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

```
extern "C" void callKernel()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        calc<<< grid, thread >>>(d_arr);
        copyElement<<< grid, thread >>>(d_arr,d_arr_part,3);
        findMax<<< grid, thread >>>(d_arr_part, d_max);
        positionChange<<< grid, thread >>>(d_arr, d_max);
    }
}
```

Above code is about computing kernels.

The functionality of kernel function is like this.

> "calc" : calculate in d_arr and update the d_arr's elements value.
>
> "copyElement" : for example, d_arr is 4step array, In the array, I just want 3rd element, so I allocate other variable d_arr_part and copy to 3rd element of d_arr to d_arr_part.
>
> "findMax" : find max value in d_arr_part and the max value is stored to d_max.
>
> "positionChange" : d_arr element is update according to d_max value.

## Problem

When I execute my program, results have no consistency. Whenever I execute, results are changed. I search this problem in google and find out that kernel function is executed concurrently. My intension is all kernel function is executed in sequence. I read NVIDIA's CUDA C programming guide at section 3.2.5. But I can't understand what to do to solve the problem. If anybody have an idea, please show me the way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your diagnosis is incorrect. Those kernels don't run concurrently becuase they are all launched into the same stream. The source of the problem is something else, probably either an error within on of the kernels or one of them not running at all. You should add error checking to your host code to see what might be going wrong

Comment: Thanks, talonmies. i'd check my kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cudaDeviceSynchronize` in between kernel executions to guarantee a sequential order. However, your code does not require this, so I think there might be a bug in your kernels.